# How to fetch JSON data in background Swiftui

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I have a JSON API I want my app to download in background.

My Quotes app send out notifications with timeintervals and I want the quotes to be in the notification.

```
struct Quotetype: Codable {
    let text: String?
    let author: String?
}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var quotes: [Quotetype]?
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    
    var quoteText: String = ""
    var quoteAuthor: String = ""
    
    init() {
        fetchQuotes()
        setUpNotificationPermission()
        setUpNotificationTriggers()
    }
    
 
    
    
    func fetchQuotes()  {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://type.fit/api/quotes") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self]  data, response, error in
            if error == nil {
                if let data = data {
                    do {
                        let jsonContent = try JSONDecoder().decode([Quotetype].self, from: data)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                            self?.quotes = jsonContent
                            if self?.quotes?.count != nil {
                                let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0..<self!.quotes!.count )
                                self?.isLoading = false
                                self?.quoteText = self!.quotes?[randomNumber].text ?? ""
                                self?.quoteAuthor = self!.quotes?[randomNumber].author ?? ""
                                
                            }
                        }
                      
                    } catch {
                        print("\(error)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Data nil")
                }
            } else {
                print("err \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func setUpNotificationTriggers() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Quote of the Day"
        content.subtitle = quoteText
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
```

this is my fetch & Notification. How can I get the quoteText in background so notification can go through?
please provide with examples.

Comment: `dataTask` can not run while your app is in background

Comment: Unrelated but why is `text` and `author` optional? The API sends no text without author and no author without text. And why is `quotes` optional? Swift relies heavily on non-optional values. Declare `quotes` as non-optional empty array.

Comment: [Using Background Tasks to Update Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app)

Comment: @vadian Because there might be empty text or author from API... there can be just text without author and vice verca

Comment: Ok , `author` can be `nil`. But a `nil` quote makes no sense.

Comment: @vardian true. I will change it now. ahaha thanks.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have seen these but since I am working with SwiftUI and I dont have  Appdelegate.      BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "net.globulus.TestBackgroundFetch", using: nil) { task in
        handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
    }

Gives me error: "Can not find handleAppRefresh" in task

Comment: SwiftUI doesn’t fetch anything. It is for UI. If u need an app delegate you just add it manually a simple google search will give you the how to

Comment: there is a method on that article `func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {` make your you implement it as well

Comment: @KakhaSepashvili SwiftUI has the option to change the life cycle when ou create a new project

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you so much ! one last Q. what about ; RefreshAppContentsOperation ?    :  let operation = RefreshAppContentsOperation().  it cant be found in scope as well.. thanks